# Handling YI on Twisted Treeline?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there an Itemization, Runes, or Masteries one could take on Twisted Treeline to handle Yi (or another auto-attack champion such as Tryndamere), given that there is no Thornmail?

To clarify, I'm not asking for a champion, I'm aware that CC will do the trick. Let's say I find myself in a 3v3 and I don't have any CC and Yi is on the enemy team. Is there anything I can do in-game or pre-game (after champ pick) to assist this?

Comment: Play jax/Malphite into Yi.  Malphite for the armor stacking Jax to dodge AAs and win a straight fight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For certain Items there are basically two: Randuins omen and Frozen heart. Both of them work really well for most champions. Randuins provides Health, Armor an attackspeed debuff and a movementspeed debuff active while Frozen heart provides Mana, Armor and Cooldown reduction with a strong attackspeed debuff aura.

Basically there is no real hardcounter item to Autoattackers but rather the basic thing you have to buy against these champions: **Armor**.

As you have already said, CC and kiting will be the most effective things to do against these champions. TT is rather bruiser and CC dominated this means you shouldn't have too much trouble handling an autoattacker, just make sure you focus him right.

Now another Item that is really effective against these champions is Wooglet's Witchcap. The only problem with it: It's only viable on AP or Hybrid Champions. The active will still force the (squishy) auttoattacker to refocus.

Comment: hmm..it's looking like playing a CC champ is really my only option haha. My team manages to feed the Yi, Trynd, etc every game so they really just kill us in a few hits regardless if we have omen or FH. I normally don't build FH though as I play manaless champs quite often. I'll try it out next time though. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Don't rely on Randuin's and Frozen Heart against Master Yi - his ultimate makes him immune to ALL slowing effects, include the effects of both those items. You want lots of hard CC to counter a Yi, and as gold efficient armor+hp as you can get (Randuin's does happen to be one of the best for this).

Comment: If you're playing pre-mades then you should be picking a team with a bunch of cc anyway. If you're not, then maybe you should consider someone with more cc :)
Personal fav against yi/yasuo/trynd: Lissandra

Comment: @clcto *"Since a change made lately, attack speed slows no longer affect Yi while using Highlander, so Randuin's Omen or Frozen Heart are much less effective against him."* ([Source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Yi/Strategy)) The wording of his ult is also pretty clear that it makes him immune to *all* slows.

Comment: Frozen Heart is also not a good counter because Yi's true damage is quite high, and without HP it's not reducing his damage nearly as much as Randuin's Omen does.